# Extracting italic text from a document

Tags: python, text, text-analysis

I have a word document with a list of species names and then various text about each species. I'd like to just extract all the species names. The obvious way to do this is to just extract all text in italics. However, I can't find a way to do this in python, does anyone have any ideas?

E.g. input: *Acanthognathus
rudis*
Small prey Solitary – 1 ? 1 ? Recruitment: Solitary, frequently catch collembola and other
small prey (GRONENBERG & al. 1998).
Size: Small, can be retrieved by one *Acromyrmex
coronatus*

ouput: Acanthognathus
rudis, Acromyrmex
coronatus

Comment: Plaese Provide Input and Output.

Comment: Try this package, https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.